# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error при подключении к БД. Как исправить?

Tags: sql, oracle, администрирование, sqlplus

Есть БД Oracle на виртуалке. Доступ с самой машины через `sqlplus` работает.
Подключиться по сети через `sqlplus` не получается.
`tnsping` по сети работает.
:

На обоих машинах в sqlnet.ora написано:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

При подключении писал

```
>SET ORACLE_SID SID
>sqlplus
  Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
  Enter password:  password
```

и получаю ошибку.

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Попробовал подключиться так:

```
"sqlplus sys/pass@tns.domain_name as sysdba"
```

Получаю ошибку

> ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

`tnsping tns.domain_name` выполняется без ошибок. К другим БД на других машинах в сети подключаюсь.
Куда посмотреть, как исправить?

Comment: А где попытка подключения по сети?

Comment: Запрос выполняется с машины из сети

Comment: sqlplus по sid это на локальной машине.  На удалённой с @tnsnalias должно быть.

Comment: Еще раз. `tnsping sid` работает. Коннект через склплюс не работает. Что надо дописать не понимаю. Можно пример?

Comment: sqlplus sys/pass@sid as sysdba  -  sid в tnsping и ORACLE_SID разные вещи,  часто совпадают,  поэтому вас это смутило.

Comment: Вы попробовали? И та же ошибка?

Comment: @0xdb дополнил ответ на основе вашего комментария. Проблему решить не удалось

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49286/discussion-between-0xdb-and-ldrakonl).

Comment: Получилось? Можно ещё попробовать с `sqlplus user/pass@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=hostname)(port=1521))(connect_data=(sid=remote_sid)))`

Comment: @0xdb подключение как Вы написали. В строке подключения ровно то, что написано в tnsnames. Почему же тогда подключение через алиас не работает?

Comment: Что прописано в sqlnet.ora? tnsping всегда берёт TNS, sqlplus смотрит в sqlnet  - например: `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)`

Comment: Оказалось, что косяк в ORACLE_HOME. Он был не задан, и куда за ТНС ходил скл плюс даже не представляю. После задания ORACLE_HOME проблема ушла

Comment: Здорово! Ну теперь уж я бубен беру.  А как tnsping и sqlplus вообще вызывались?

Comment: Просто из cmd. пример вызова sqlplus'a есть в вопросе. `tnsping tns.domain`. Даже оба примера есть в вопросе

Comment: Я имел ввиду - как они вообще находились без ORACLE_HOME? Наверное  весь путь к оракловскому бин гвоздями к PATH прибит. Если под виндой, то по моему где-то так надо: `set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подведу итоги комментариям.

Для подключения к удалённой базе устанавливать ORACLE_SID не имеет смысла. Установив эту переменную можно подключиться по *Bequeath* протоколу без указания строки соединения и без участия прослушивателя, но только на той же машине, на которой установлена база, т.е. локально.

Если на клиентской машине установлено несколько клиентов настоятельно рекомендуеся файлы сетевой конфигурации, tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora и др., поместить в отдельную папку (где угодно) и создать переменную окружения TNS_ADMIN указываюшую на эту папку.

Порядок поиска файлов на Windows:

- окружение TNS_ADMIN
- реестр TNS_ADMIN
- %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin

ORACLE_HOME из окружения всегда имеет преимущество над записью из рееестра.

Использование реестра плохо документировано, т.е. какой дом оракла будет найден в различных клиентах, судя по диспутам на различных форумах, не совсем понятно.
Насколько мне известно - если убираешь базу с машины с экзотической операционкой, надо обязательно ручками почистить реестер, чтобы его устаревшие записи потом где-то опять не всплыли. Повидимому тоже самое относится и к клиентам.

В данном конкретном случае, по видимому tnsping и sqlplus нашли два различных tnsnames.оra и только установкой окружения ORACLE_HOME удалось добится желаемого результата.

Comment: прокомментируйте вот это утверждение, пожалуйста "Для подключения к удалённой базе устанавливать ORACLE_SID не нужно. Эта переменная дествительна только для машины, на которой установлена база."

Comment: SID это site identifer, который вместе с oracle_home определят уникальный  `key` для подсоединения к SGA. Узнать его можно - `select instance from v$thread`.  Зачем он вам нужен на клиентской машине?